# Change SharedPreference from String to Set<String>

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have an old published app with custom MultiSelectListPreference elements. I want to change them into "official" AndroidX MultiSelectListPreference. The old elements have saved their preferences as String, but AndroidX MultiSelectListPreference uses a String Set.

I would like to know if there is a best practice how to change the preferences when a user updates the app, so that the settings aren't lost.

Do I have to use new preference keys for the new elements or can I keep the old ones? Is there a secure point in time where I can start an update routine, so that I can be sure that no internal Android process tried to access the preferences before, expecting the new String Set, while there are still the old Strings?

Any help would be appreciated.